# Trying to add file information to a list but Jupyter won't run the code

Tags: python

I am trying to add the content of a file into a list using a for loop. This is the code:

```
infile = open('Cities.txt', 'r')
cities = []

line = infile.readline()

while line != '':
    cities.append(infile)
    infile.close()

print(cities)
```

But when I try to run it, Jupyter refuses to run it and stays stuck with In[*]. As far as I know, this is not an infinite loop. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you want to read the whole content of the file till the end or do you just want to read all the lines till there is an empty line ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
with open('Cities.txt', 'r') as file:
    cities = file.readlines()
```

Now `cities` is a list containing all the lines of your file.

The `file.readlines()` method returns a string with all the lines from that file.

Answer (score 0):

You never reassign `line` within the `for` loop, so the `while` loop will run infinitely if the first line in the file isn't empty. You're also appending the file handle, rather than the line inside the file, to `cities`, which is probably not what you're looking for.

Instead, use a `for` loop to read over every line in the file:

```py
infile = open('Cities.txt', 'r')
cities = []

for line in file:
    line_to_add = line.rstrip() # remove trailing "\n"
    if line_to_add == '':
         break
    cities.append(line_to_add)

infile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches to get a list that contains all lines of file, such as using `readlines` or using a for loop over lines (the last one is not suggested). You can also read the file and explode it using `\n` which indicates a new line(break line):

```py
cities = open("Cities.txt").read().split("\n")
cities
```

In the case `Cities.txt` file contains the following:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

The result would be:

```
['line 1', 'line 2', 'line 3', 'line 4']
```

Note that using `readlines` would result in something like:

```py
cities = open("Cities.txt").readlines()
cities
# result ['line 1\n', 'line 2\n', 'line 3\n', 'line 4']
```

In this case, if you want to strip the `\n` out, you should probably use `map` function to apply a function on the elements:

```py
cities = list(map(str.strip, open("Cities.txt").readlines()))
cities
```

This would result in something like:

```
['line 1', 'line 2', 'line 3', 'line 4']
```

Note that the first argument of the `map`, is a function that would be applied to each element of the second argument, which is an iterable object.